# slickgrid viewportchanged event not firing

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Can't get slick grid viewportChanged event to fire. It is supposed to be fired on page load. Any ideas?

javascript:

```
grid.onViewportChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    alert('sdfsdfaasdfdsaf');
    var vp = grid.getViewport();
    loader.ensureData(vp.top, vp.bottom);
});
```

CS:

```
namespace OrderCatalog
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

        }
        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not supposed to fire on page load.  As the name suggests, it fires when the viewport changes, i.e. when the user scrolls and the top and bottom visible rows in the viewport change.

Comment: this one bit me as well.  It'd be nice if there was an event fired when the viewport was finished during the initial data fill.